# What is 'BOOST_PATH' in iotivity?

Tags: iotivity

What is 'BOOST_PATH' in iotvity?

===================================================

2. Modify the BOOST path in the Makefile

To build, set the BOOST_PATH environment variable in Makefile.

## boost folder path.

BOOST_PATH=/home/iotivity/Desktop/boost_1_56_0.

https://wiki.iotivity.org/getting_started_iotivity_services_for_linux

Answer (score 0):

Other alternative is to install

```
sudo apt-get install libboost1.55-all
```

This will install as well as it will set the path correctly